# Seeking 1980s cartoon that had a gas that damaged or mutated robots

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

In the early 1980s, I remember seeing a western-style cartoon that featured a scientist who had created a kind of gas that damaged robot's machinery.  I can't recall whether the scientist was evil or not.  However, the bad guys (whoever they were) got wind of this invention, and there was a race between to recover the gas cylinder from where the scientist had hidden it.  A robot with the good guys' mission to retrieve it was accidentally exposed to the gas and damaged, and in the confusion, the bad guys got away with the cylinder.

The villains then modified the gas, so that instead of just damaging robots, it "mutated" them and turned them evil.  Then they released the gas in domed city, and all the worker robots started attacking the population.  They people were evacuated and the dome sealed, but I remember the good guys watching video footage of overgrown construction robots trying to break out of the dome.

That's all I remember.  Does anybody know what this show was?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer, since this has [just been released](https://www.wbshop.com/products/mighty-orbots-the-complete-series-mod?AID=10811526&PID=3821628&ref=CJP) as a Manufacture-On-Demand DVD set.  I was looking for "The Phoenix Factor," the eighth episode of *[Might Orbots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mighty_Orbots)*.

Per [Arioch's* Well of Souls](http://www.well-of-souls.com/orbots/episodes.htm):

> Umbra awakens the cyborg scientist Doctor Phoenix, exiled from Earth 200 years ago. Wary of Umbra but hungry for revenge, Dr. Phoenix agrees to use his outlawed Mechanogen energy virus to help Shadow. Phoenix is surprised by Mighty Orbots in the Danger Zone (where outlawed devices are dumped) while trying to retrieve his Mechanogen; in the encounter, Ohno is infected with the virus. While Rob struggles to cure Ohno, Dr. Phoenix releases a mutated version of the virus on Earth, where it begins to take control of everything mechanical. Rondu orders the evacuation of the city, and it is quaratined by erecting a force field dome... but this is only a temporary measure; the dome can't hold for long. Galactic Patrol sensors detect Phoenix's cloaked vessel in orbit, and Mighty Orbots (including ailing Ohno) head out in pursuit. By using Boo to match wavelengths with the cloaking field, they neutralize it and soon work their way inside the massive ship. They confront Dr. Phoenix and are on the verge of convicing him to switch sides (he has been chafing against Umbra's control, and Ohno assures him   that the anti-cyborg fears of 200 years ago are gone, and now "humans and robots work together") when an eavesdropping Umbra releases the last of the Mechanogen inside Phoenix's ship... and all over Phoenix and the Orbots!

The episode is also viewable online, but I am hiding the URL, since it's in a nest of spyware.

> https://kisscartoon.pro/the-mighty-orbots/season/1/episode/08/

*What is Arioch doing still around?  Wasn't he slain by the Black Sword's Brothers, before the creation of our world?